# Как расположить кнопки сверху, в центре и снизу экрана

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

У меня есть три кнопки

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Красный"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Зелёный"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Синий"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Как сделать, что бы первая кнопка была сверху, вторая - в центре, а третья снизу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете добавить меж кнопками вьюхи, которые займут всё оставшееся место на экране, поделив его поровну с помощью веса:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Красный"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Зелёный"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <Space
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Синий"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Либо замените их родителя на RelativeLayout и проставьте средней кнопке свойство

```
android:centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       />

    <Button
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: А как сделать что бы при на жатии на кнопку менялся цвет фона?

Comment: Оооо, да это целое дело)) поищи уроки стартандроид

Comment: Я просто новичек в этом деле

Comment: И не умею гуглить

Comment: А ссылку можешь скинуть?

Comment: startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html - это в текстовом виде. И www.youtube.com/watch?v=ac8y518CIng&list=PLyfVjOYzujugap6Rf3ETNKkx4v9ePllNK - канал этого чувака. Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо но я уже сделал